# Express eigenvectors of $A^{-1}$ in terms of eigenvectors of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know the eigenvalues of the matrix $A^{-1}$ are $\frac{1}{\lambda_n}$ where $\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. I didn't know their eigenvectors were related; in what way are they related?

Also how would you prove that $(BC)^{-1} = C^{-1}B^{-1}$? Because I have no idea where to start on that.

Comment: Think vectors: $Av=u$ means $A^{-1}u=v$.

Comment: The two questions here ought to be asked separately, but the second has surely been answered on this site before.

Comment: For the last question: Look at the two products $(BC)(C^{-1}B^{-1})$ and $(C^{-1}B^{-1})(BC)$, and see for yourself that they are indeed inverses of one another.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** If $A$ is invertible and ${\bf w} = A {\bf v}$, then ${\bf v} = A^{-1} {\bf w}$. How does this specialize if $\bf v$ is an eigenvector of $A$?

Comment: Are they $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ times the eigenvectors of A?

Comment: Every nonzero multiple $\mu {\bf v}$ of an eigenvector $\bf v$ of a matrix $B$ is another eigenvector of $B$ of the same eigenvalue $\lambda$: $$B (\mu {\bf v}) = \mu \cdot B{\bf v} = \mu (\lambda {\bf v}) = \lambda (\mu {\bf v}) .$$

Comment: @Karacoreable The _size_ of an eigenvector is irrelevant in this setting. So asking whether $\frac1\lambda$ times an eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $A^{-1}$ looks strange. Instead, ask whether an eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvecor of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @Arthur Ah, so they are the same, since the multiple in front we say doesn't actually change the eigenvector?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for the second question. By the definition of inverses, we have the following:

$$BC \cdot (BC)^{-1}=I$$

In order to get from $BC$ to $I$, you want to cancel out the $C$ on the right and then cancel out the $B$. How would this be written in terms of $B^{-1}$ and $C^{-1}$?

Comment: Pre-multiply by first $B^{-1}$ then $C^{-1}$? That's a good hint, thank you!

Comment: You want to cancel out $C$ first, so multiply by $C^{-1}$ first and then $B^{-1}$.

Comment: I do have to pre-multiply though, don't I? Because order matters? So if I do C first then don't I get $C^{-1}BC(BC)^{-1} = C^{-1}$, then do B inverse so $B^{-1}C^{-1} BC (BC)^{-1}= B^{-1}C^{-1}$, leads to $B^{-1}C^{-1} =B^{-1}C^{-1}$? Or can I put the matrices in between $BC$ and $(BC^){-1}$? Sorry, might well be a silly question.

Comment: I mean if you pre-multiply on one side you have to pre-multiply on the other, so how does multiplying by a matrix in the middle mean you multiply the other side? Doesn't matter with just identity matrix the first time, but the second time you have a matrix on the other side already.

Comment: Don't worry, just tried it, I get it!

Comment: What I meant is that you start with $BC$, multiply by $C^{-1}$ to get $BCC^{-1}=B$, and then multiply by $B^{-1}$ to get $BB^{-1}=I$. Now that you know you can multiply $BC$ by $C^{-1}$ and then $B^{-1}$ to get $I$, what is the inverse of $BC$?

Answer (score 1):

$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}\\
A = PDP^{-1}\\
A^{-1} = PD^{-1}P^{-1}$